Wanted but not invoked, although invoked
i am getting the following result from Mockito output
Wanted but not invoked:
childObj.method5(<any>);
-> at de.tejoe.ViewTest.init(ViewTest.java:36)

However, there were exactly 5 interactions with this mock:
childObj.method1("foo");
-> at de.tejoe.View.init(View.java:257)

childObj.method2([null]);
-> at de.tejoe.View.init(View.java:258)

childObj.method3();
-> at de.tejoe.View.initAlarms(View.java:259)

childObj.method4(true);
-> at de.tejoe.View.init(View.java:261)

childObj.method5(de.tejoe.View$ViewListener@1c82b8ef);
-> at de.tejoe.View.init(View.java:262)

Mockito states, that the method5 was not invoked with any parameter and at the same time the output says, method5 was invoked, with some not null parameter
Mockito Version used
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.12.4'

P.S. I saw there are dozents of "wanted but not invoked"-questions here, but I did not find a single one, where the output stated that the method was invoked indeed.
i tried to create a prototype containing the example and the classes involved. However the prototype code is fully functional. I think the main important thing to learn from this is, that there are two different method signatures for method5
class MockitoErrorTest
{
  interface A
  {
    void method5(Object x);
  }

  private class AImpl implements A
  {
    public void method5(Object x) {}
  }

  private class B extends AImpl
  {
    void method1(String x) {}
    void method2(Object[] x) {}
    void method3() {}
    void method4(boolean flag) {}
    void method5(PropertyChangeListener x) {}
  }

  private class C
  {
    B child;
    B getChild()
    {
      return child;
    }
    void init()
    {
      B x = getChild();
      x.method1("foo");
      x.method2(new Object[] {null});
      x.method3();
      x.method4(true);
      x.method5(new PropertyChangeListener()
      {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt){}
      });
    }
  }

  @Test
  void init()
  {
    C vo = mock(C.class);
    B childObj = mock(B.class);
    when(vo.getChild()).thenReturn(childObj);
    doCallRealMethod().when(vo).init();

    vo.init();
    verify(childObj).method3();
    verify(childObj).method4(true);
    //in this prototype the verification works
    //in the production code this one fails
    //i cannot spot any differences
    verify(childObj).method5(any());
  }
}


I think we're going to need an [mcve] for this.

Is method5 overloaded?

so far i failed to create such reproducable example. I added the test code, however the example is working. But you may want to look at the example to understand the type herarchy

looks like overloading, can you try verify(childObj).method5(any(PropertyChangeListener.class));

@SitherTsering thank you, that was the answer. That solved the problem for me

Explanation: When you're using any() without specifying the type, Mockito might not know which overloaded method you are referring to. By explicitly using the argument matcher for the specific type, such as any(PropertyChangeListener.class), you are telling Mockito to verify the correct version of the overloaded method.
